# Who's responsible when someone runs into the Mikvah upon my swipe

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath, gezel-stealing

Many *Mikvahs* these days have a gate that opens upon swiping a pre-paid card. I've had many times where a person will stand there and wait for me to swipe and go in with me after I swipe my card.

Do I have to worry about *Geneiva* and not allow him, or is it completely on him and it's the person getting in without paying who is *Oiver*  on *Geneiva*. ?

This question applies not necessary on *Mikvah* gates, that's just a scenario where it happens a lot.

Comment: You are the custodian of the mikveh? Don't you think that the owner of the mikveh need to check this alone? If he don't check this is perhaps a sign that he knows this and is mevater.

Comment: @kouty I'm not the custodian, I'm entering the Mikvah with my pre-paid card, the owner is not there and not aware what's happening. I paid for it and allowed only one swipe per day.

Comment: I tend to ask them how they intend on paying. They usually have a response  that solves the problem - like they forgot their card at home and will pay next time.

Comment: Why would this be any different than being given the keys to somebody's house, and letting other people sneak in with you?